# How do I make my plot look like this with matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

So right now I'm trying to simulate a Poisson process for an assignment, here's the code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

y = np.arange(0,21,1)
x = np.cumsum(np.random.exponential(2,21))

print(y)
print(x)

sns.set()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The problem arises when I try plotting it. The code above, as expected, produces a normal matplotlib plot that looks like this:

[image]

However I need it to look like this:

[image]

Is there an easy way of doing it? I tried messing with bar plots but was unable to produce something that looks good.

Comment: Replace `plt.plot(x,y)` with `plt.step(x,y)`. I am not sure if you are just looking for the step graph or want to reduce the number of data-points as well.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa yes, thank you, I didn't know how such a plot was called so I had trouble looking for it even after checking matplotlib documentation. Thank you, this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

The graph that you are wanting to plot is called as step plot in matplotlib. In order to plot it replace `plt.plot(x,y)` with `plt.step(x,y)`

So, your code becomes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

y = np.arange(0,21,1)
x = np.cumsum(np.random.exponential(2,21))

print(y)
print(x)

sns.set()
plt.step(x,y)
plt.show()
```